# how to remove an style from material ui component

Tags: material-ui

I know its possible to use "sx" prop or createTheme() function to override an style in material ui component. but is there any way to **remove** any of default styles from its components?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use genereic css property.

`all: "initial"`

```
<Button sx={{ all: "initial" }}>Click me</Button>

<Button style={{ all: "initial" }}>Click me</Button>
```

When you use it its going to reset the stylisation of the component and after it you can write your own.

Comment: Well there are other values to the `all` property, you shuold try them, I'm not saying its going to work 100% of the time, but if you try it on the button component you are going to see it "rise and shine"...